# How to use Google Analytics with jQuery form

Tags: jquery, forms, google-analytics

I've a form that sends the data to the server via jQuery.

Usually, with a thank you page, it's easy to track the submitted forms using Google Analytics but since there is no thank you page (because the data is sent asynchronously), how can I track those forms submitted ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Google Analytics' [trackPageview function](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55529) in the function called upon form submission.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/choose/a/path']);
```